# Mailcore: fetchMessagesOperationWithFolder in reverse order

Tags: mailcore2

I run fetchMessagesOperationWithFolder to get all the messages in the inbox. I want to cycle through these and save the structures. I use a for loop to cycle through the messages array and then run fetchMessageOperationWithFolder to get the data for each message. It seems to start with the oldest message in the inbox instead of the newest. Is there a way to specify the order of the messages or do I have to manually reverse the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servers will generally return message from older to more recent but I don't think that's guaranteed.
mailcore2 will keep that order.

MCOIMAPMessage have a field uid, which is the UID message attribute of IMAP.
Generally, on IMAP, for a given folder, the lower the UID is, the older the message is.
It will help you run through the array in the order you like.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of using the UID's.